# QPython 3 console

Tags: qpython, qpython3

I've recently begun programming with QPython3 on my android phone, and I've found it slightly annoying that the console pops up whenever I run a script. I often have it sending the output through a Toast since I usually only need the information for a second.

Is there a way I can make it, either within my script or in the settings of QPython3, that the console is default to the background while running a script?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the "#qpy:console" into your script, does it work for you ?